# No audio codecs on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, audio

I've been trying to listen to music in Fedora 21 but unfortunately I cannot.

Here is what I tried:

```
yum update
yum install gstreamer gstreamer-plugins-good gstreamer-plugins-bad gstreamer-plugins-ugly gstreamer-ffmpeg
```

Without any success. I have no idea what I'm missing. Rythmbox just doesn't play the music and Audacious says "**No decoder found**".

Comment: How is your music encoded? Is it MP3?

Comment: Yes! Mp3. @JohnWHSmith

Comment: Add the RPMFusion repo. http://free.rpmfusion.org/.

Comment: I tried wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch.rpm && yum install rpmfusion-free-release-21.noarch.rpm

wget http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm && yum install rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm but it didn't install anything. It says: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-21.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do. So I guess they are already there.

Comment: And then a `yum update`?

Answer (score 1):

@Doryan the current instructions for RPMFusion free are at http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration

That *should* make available MP3 codecs.

I believe they can then be installed manually in the form of the `gstreamer-plugins-ugly` package, if necessary.

I have it working on my Fedora 22 system somehow.  `gstreamer-ffmpeg` is not installed on my system.  But there is `gstreamer1-libav` installed, as well as `ffmpeg`.  (I'd be more specific if I could figure out what rhythmbox was using; I can't see anything relevant in `lsof`!)

According to the Unofficial Fedora Faq, Audacious will additionally require the package `audacious-plugins-freeworld-mp3`.

If you have problems beyond that, please confirm which of the above packages you have installed, which music player, the specific version of Fedora... that's all I can think of for now.

Comment: It was gstreamer-1-libav that was missing! Thank you so much!